# IE 8 and 9 and CSS Gradient Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

if you go to http://www.aerlawgroup.com on IE 8 or 9, you can see that the CTA button shows up in a weird red color, rather than the intended orange gradient.

Does anyone know how to fix it so it renders as intended?  Thanks.

```
   .button2 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    border: 1px solid #a56317;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background: #992828;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffb14a), to(#c76e08));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb14a, #c76e08);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffb14a, #c76e08);
    text-shadow: #764711 1px 1px 1px;
    font: normal normal bold 18px arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*top: 248px;
    left: 97px;*/
}
.button2:hover,
.button2:focus {
    border: 1px solid #ec8d21;
    background: #992828;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffd459), to(#ef840a));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffd459, #ef840a);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffd459, #ef840a);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button2:active {
    background: #982727;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#996a2c), to(#c76e08));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #996a2c, #c76e08);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #996a2c, #c76e08);
}
```

Comment: sorry.  I don't know how I forgot that.  Too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IE9-, `background:linear-gradient` or the vendor-specific syntaxes will not work because that is CSS3, you need to use their old-school proprietary syntax:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb14a', endColorstr='#c76e08',GradientType=0 );
```

Put that at the **bottom** of the CSS assignment for that button, and you should be safe. If you still don't see it, add this:

```
zoom:1;
```

For non-block items, this is necessary sometimes for the gradient to take effet.

Comment: That worked!  Dude, you're amazing.  How did you know that?  Thank you and Happy New Years to you.

Comment: @user3117275 - sadly, ur not the first soldier on the IE battlefield haha. Happy New Years to you too, boss.